# Multiplicative undelta

Tags: code-golf, array, integer

Let us define the *"multiplicative deltas"* of values \$[\; a_0, \cdots a_N, \;]\$ as:

$$
[\; a_1 / a_0, \cdots, a_{i+1} / a_i, \cdots, a_N / a_{N-1} \;]
$$

The reverse operation - namely *"multiplicative undelta"* - returns values such that the above operation results in the given values.

#### Example

Given values \$[\; 1, 5, 3, 2 \;]\$ a general solution to the "*multiplicative undelta*" operation is:

$$
[\;
 a_0,
 \quad \underset{a_1}{\underbrace{a_0 \cdot 1}},
 \quad \underset{a_2}{\underbrace{a_1 \cdot 5}},
 \quad \underset{a_3}{\underbrace{a_2 \cdot 3}},
 \quad \underset{a_4}{\underbrace{a_3 \cdot 2}}
 \;]
$$

A particular solution can be obtained by setting \$a_0\$ to any value other than zero, for example by setting \$a_0 := 1 \$ we would get:

$$
[\; 1, 1, 5, 15, 30 \;]
$$

### Challenge

Your task for this challenge is to implement the operation "*multiplicative undelta*" as defined above.

### Rules

Inputs are:

- a non-zero value \$a_0\$
- a non-empty list/array/vector/... of non-zero "*multiplicative deltas*"

Output is a list/array/vector/... of values such that the first element is \$a_0\$ and for which the "*multiplicative deltas*" are the input.

**Note:** If your language has no support of negative integers you may replace *non-zero* by *positive*.

### Test cases

```
2 [21] -> [2,42]
1 [1,5,3,2] -> [1,1,5,15,30]
-1 [1,5,3,2] -> [-1,-1,-5,-15,-30]
7 [1,-5,3,2] -> [7,7,-35,-105,-210]
2 [-12,3,-17,1311] -> [2,-24,-72,1224,1604664]
-12 [7,-1,-12,4] -> [-12,-84,84,-1008,-4032]
1 [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] -> [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]
```

Comment: May we take a single list of length 1+number of deltas, where the first item is a₀?

Comment: @Adám: I'm gonna say no to that because it would change things for existing answers.

Answer (score 18):

### Haskell, 8 bytes

```
scanl(*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xDsIwDEV3TuGBoUX2YBeUqScpHaJAoCKEqOH8ddMxKsjbe19Pftr8uoegvr9qdjaG5tTq204Rerh9DgBpnuIXjuBBYBAeK8QwMF6wQ6l5Q9z@UWbj9EOUPLEUTmyQO@ZdUkrTFI3b7rz7RLC6URfng31kJZfSCg)

Comment: I was checking if anyone wrote this, and I thought noone wrote it and I said "cool, then I'll write" and then saw your answer at the bottom of the page. upvoted.

Answer (score 9):

## APL(Dyalog), 3 bytes

```
×\∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//8PSYRx1dMFrBSEHDyFCTC8ozVNAwVDBVMFYwggsBFRxab2gEFANS5gqGxoaGmgA)

If I have to take the number on the left and the array on the right:

*-2 thanks to @H.PWiz*

**<s>7</s> <s>5</s> 3 bytes**

`×\,`

Comment: `⊣,⊢` can just be `,`

Comment: @H.PWiz thanks, my tacit is extremely weak

Comment: You don't need the parens; `×\,` evaluates to a function.

Comment: @Dennis Doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: You don't need to count the parens, because they're not needed in some situations. ``f←×\`` works, for example. Btw, the `(-12 3 -17 1311)` in your permalink should be `(¯12 3 ¯17 1311)`.

Comment: @Dennis I'm not really sure on this, but if it only works when defined as a function then wouldn't you need to include that definition in the bytecount, keeping it at 5?

Comment: It *has* to work as a function (or a full program) to be valid. Snippets aren't allowed as submissions.

Comment: Dennis is most probably trying to say that anonymous functions are allowed (they are). Parentheses are unnecessary; for example, we don't wrap Python lambdas in parentheses, they're not needed, similarly for Dyalog. Sure, `lambda x:x+1(7)` won't return `8` in Python, and `(lambda x:x+1)(7)` will, but `f=lambda x:x+1` and then `f(7)` will return `8`; the parentheses aren't part of the function. Note that this doesn't hold true for the `{}` (i.e. the `lambda:` part in Python) around dfns.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 15 bytes

```r
cumprod(scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7k0t6AoP0WjODkxT0NT8785l6GCrqmCsYLRfwA)

Full program. Function is longer (unless we were allowed to "glue" the inputs together, so that built-in `cumprod` would suffice as a complete answer):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(i,x)cumprod(c(i,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7BCoAgDADQe1/h0cF22Cy89DeG0CENSejvTSuKiMHY3hhbKn6k4nNw2xyDnnEHl5c1xUm7s4PitaAShs5rRuVqGtCgQAP6ib2AXpEmxFKB2CIb5nv3nNiq2OoenhOCn6hPHA)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
hYp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyOy4P9/Q65oQwUjBWMF01gA)

```
            #implicit input, x_0 and A
h           #horizontally concatenate
Yp          #cumulative product
            #implicit output
```

The `hYp`e about MATL is real.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 39 bytes

```
def f(a,b):
    for x in[1]+b:a*=x;yield a
```

Alternative approach. [Returns a generator.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI1EnSdOKizMtv0ihQiEzL9owVjvJKlHLtsK6MjM1J0Uh8X9BUWZeiUZOZnGJRpqGkU60kWGspqYmF4qwoU60oY6pjrGOEaacrqGRgk60uY6uIRAZ6ZiAVPwHAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 14 bytes

```
FoldList@Times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8tPyfFJ7O4xCEkMze1@L@Cg4NCtbFOtZEOFNbWxv4HAA)

`FoldList[Times, a0, {x1, x2, ..., xn}]` produces the desired output. `FoldList[Times]` is the curried form that produces a pure function still waiting for its `a0` and `{x1, x2, ..., xn}`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

Takes input as `(m)(a)`.

```javascript
m=>a=>[m,...a.map(x=>m*=x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDRbsIwDEXf@Yo8ttNNiN006Uv6I1UeIgYIRCmCaeLvOxdNaO3YEtuKZJ2bax/zZ75trofLhz4P79txF8c@tjm2XQ9jTDZ9vhT32PZv8V6mcTOcb8Npa07DvtgVSnFZdExJ/TxlqdZr1TEcp9USIAEINSpwWgCEqUHSs784/Q@nCVPUUiVfwCo8YD2jv@GAIMzEWilML@hpRk0ssKYAqkjmfc6o2UEHBrE8yFvnvVtKCCwS4eFSdFyauxeRxkFCPNgG2tnqj8UxZjc9FyeiaOR7VAwvPrgB1z6NXw)

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 3 bytes

```
å*V
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=5SpW&input=WzEsLTUsMywyXQo3)

---

### Explanation

```
        :Implicit input of array U and integer V
å       :Cumulatively reduce U
 *      :By multiplication
  V     :With an initial value of V
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
;×\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/68PSY////6xoa/Y8219E1BCIjHZNYAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 9 bytes

```perl6
{[\*] @_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjpGK1bBIb72vzVXcWKlQpqGrqGRjkK0uY6CriEIAzkmsZrW/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Standard ML](http://sml-family.org/), 32 bytes

```ml
fun f(x::r)a=a::f r(a*x)|f&a=[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLasNADEXXyVcIL4od5GDJ4wcOzr67QhdduA4MAbeBeBySaUmh@NddTfMgwS3zRLrnjkaHdhu2W9uZYWg@DDT@sSj2gS51UTSw9/XsGHw3D7qsdD186i20X0/7jbFQwu737MBvDBygXIJXebCS6wq8@tV4geSerYje5uvOrLV92dh38NCTeKt38Gjs3HYnxWI6vRj7DVRMNXCwmEwm/gzCpQRQcQ2z4E5FmGCMEicnPSsJXZgkE/0P9LdESOhmIrusP7H@zGU3WIaZqB0VycY05npiwXrKkGK6/Oj6oZAVhhkjsVwojVSaqpFFJjg6H@WK5ruqxSJXKFMqiHIMVRSPe8R4N069urZKfDGXxzFmTKUKzpGT1JkMPw)

**Ungolfed:**

```ml
fun f (x::xr) a = a :: f xr (a*x)
  | f    _    a = [a]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>6</strike> 5 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Bubbler

```
*/\@,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9LP8ZB578ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr6CkUKagpEhhG0IZBsqmCoYKxhBBOIxRMzBAvFIIiAD4g2NgALxhuYKhsaGhjC9IBlzkBkgpgnCCiNU@B8A)

### Explanation:

A diadic verb, the left argument is `a0`, the rigth one - the vector

```
     @, - append the vector to a0 and 
  */\   - find the running product
```

Comment: [`*/\@,` works exactly the same.](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9LP8ZB578ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr6CkUKagpEhhG0IZBsqmCoYKxhBBOIxRMzBAvFIIiAD4g2NgALxhuYKhsaGhjC9IBlzkBkgpgnCCiNU@B8A "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Bubbler Yes, of course! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 22 bytes

```factor
[ prefix cum-product ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCsIwEETv@Yr5gRQSlYKCV/HiRTyJhxBTDNo2JltQSr@9JhalFncuy9thdrdQmmrfH/bb3WYJFUKtA67GV@aGYO6NqbQJKBVdskCKbCAbDc4boqfztiKsGGsZYrVRUqCDRPcFAgvMEondP8p/Mf/wfIS5kJFykUPMxHRBniKSY/5OG4/kRMMNHeuP6YHCPqCbkjtfnxtNOPXF8P@6VA5Z/wI)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 69 bytes

```
@set/pa=
@echo %a%
@for %%d in (%*) do @set/aa*=%%d&call echo %%a%%
```

Takes input of \$a_0\$ on STDIN and the deltas as command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
\{\o*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z@mOiZf6/9/Q4VoQx1THWMdo1gA)

<s>I think this could be 5 bytes (`\{\o*`) but `\` instruction seems a little off when dealing with input.</s> This is now fixed in the latest version.

#### Explanation:

```
\       Swap arguments, pushing both to stack
 {      Foreach loop over second argument
  \o    Output counter with newline
    *   Multiply counter by current element
        Implicitly output the last element
```

Comment: I have redesigned the handling of `\` with implicit input. It still handles items on the stack the same way, but now it pops two elements from the input onto the stack instead of just one. I think it could be useful for this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
*FR._s
```

[Test that one here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aFR._s&input=2%2C+%5B-12%2C3%2C-17%2C1311%5D%0A&debug=0)

Alternatively, 7 bytes:

```
.u*NYEQ
```

[Test it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.u%2aNYEQ&input=2%0A%5B-12%2C3%2C-17%2C1311%5D%0A&debug=0)

The first takes input as a tuple, the second takes input as two separate lines.

Thanks to @Sok for helping me with getting good at mapping and saving 1 byte.

Comment: You can save a byte by implementing the map in the second solution as `R`, as in `*FR._s` - [demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aFR._s&input=%5B1%2C%5B1%2C5%2C3%2C2%5D%5D&debug=0)

Comment: @Sok Nice catch! I had tried `M` assuming it'd work, then got a sugar parse failure - mostly because I didn't remember how the parsing for `F <pf2>` worked.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't really understand how nested `M`, `F`, `L`, and `R` work, I just tried a bunch until one worked :o)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 67 bytes

```
(lambda(a l &aux(y 1))(mapcar(lambda(x)(setf y(* y x)))(cons a l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgFESvMqsagxYW0Xl@ViBYiRbo6c0W7Yb33hhnoy/0wZ6GhU6OZRUKHBp5EjO0UjzEGwm/TIpxu3dkdshIqgbmOiPqqe6CGS01@gkjhg@8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
G*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/313r////hv@jDXVMdYx1jGIB)

This is equivalent to [nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173538/62393) in Haskell: `scanl(*)`, which means reduce from the left using multiplication, and return all partial results.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>5</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
šηP
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@BMO*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6MJz2wP@/9c1NOKKNtfRNQQiIx2TWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/u5ulir6SQmJeioGQPZj5qmwRkFv8/uvDc9oD/Ov@NuKKNDGO5DLmiDXVMdYx1jGK5dJE55iC2LpQDVKxraARk6xqa6xgaGxqCFAMFzYECOiAZE7BJRjooMBYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
š      # Prepend the (implicit) input-integer at the start of the (implicit) input-list
       #  i.e. -12 and [7,-1,-12,4] → ["-12",7,-1,-12,4]
 η     # Prefixes of this new list
       #  i.e. ["-12",7,-1,-12,4]
       #   → [["-12"],["-12",7],["-12",7,-1],["-12",7,-1,-12],["-12",7,-1,-12,4]]
  P    # Take the product of each inner list (and output implicitly)
       #  i.e. [["-12"],["-12",7],["-12",7,-1],["-12",7,-1,-12],["-12",7,-1,-12,4]]
       #   → [-12,-84,84,-1008,-4032]
```

Comment: No, the `s` was there to get the other input. :) `s` is swap, and `š` is prepending at the start of the list. Either way, thanks for the -2

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:[a]+(b and f(a*b[0],b[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYrBCsIwEAXvfkWOG30Fd1WEgl@y5LBLCRZqLDYXvz5tjyLMaWbmb32@i7SWH5O9fLBg8F4tnciDlSFksqPrOcGV@xRjmz9jqTSNS6VMAhXebDz8aIYybrhA/lvHEqB3dLwhuO5HWwE)

Surprisingly, the move to Python 3 and use of generators there only saves 1 byte over the recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 29 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$a;$b|%{($a*=$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJUyXRWiWpRrUayNWyVYnXrP3//7@hgoahjqmOsY6RJgA)

This assumes just outputting the values is fine.

```powershell
> .\scratch.ps1 1 (1,5,3,2)
1
1
5
15
30
```

If that's not fine, this actually builds the list and then pushes it to toString which prints the same way.

```powershell
param($a,$b)$c=,$a;$b|%{$c+=$_*$c[-1]};$c #41 bytes
```

Comment: Rules are: `Output is a list/array/vector/`. So, the first is fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 47 bytes

```
f(k,l)=∏_{n=1}^{[1...l.length+1]}join(k,l)[n]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oymvkmcaku)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fph597nbql)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
{x,x*\y}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxlj8uKwkAQRff5iloPt7Cr+hUMuPUjNIswJJpNRkwWivjvVnygMvTtouk69bjd8nLC6Wd7vhbFgtbt0B6bqR92NLXjRL/N2I7U/R1p2vcjmQ5NPxTdRiuo1LQgXtFGEbS2T6mEInnSV0IgiJAI7+Y8/wNYMCtatPugskH8RWVkS86Qs6Byx7RiUaNYMomXj2VYAzgrRO0hyYWUwmO8Vtl4mgvDewWrKANM1t+V4OD8047S13nbMscorTe8ItkQLaEx1Tc0jkqX)

Another easier-than-I-thought problem. `\` is the scan operator.

Comment: Shuffling thing around a bit, I think this can just be `*\,`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 3 bytes

```
pɖ*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJwyZYqIiwiIiwiLTFcblsxLDUsMywyXSJd)

```
p   # Prepend
 ɖ* # Cumulative product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 16 bytes

```perl
$b||=1;say$b*=$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lqabG1tC6OLFSJUnLViX@/39DLkMuUy5jLqN/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/uvmAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda n,A:reduce(lambda a,c:a+[a[-1]*c],A,[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NCsJADIXXeors2mpmkVQRBhR6jjGLsT9YqNNS6sLTj9NpEReFhPA@Xl4yfKZn79g317vv7OtRWXBY6LGu3mWdrsRiqe3RWKNIDqVggcZJ5pt@nM3QOjCGEQyTSBi09BkhR@CI1Aa7LEj9M45ejkRRcFBOtCbwsjNHRXH6HQtio0RE73fD2LoJ0vBnhgmoGyTYROW/)

Comment: It may be of interest to you that a python solution is shorter in python 3 using generators

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＩＥ⁺⟦Ｎ⟧ＡΠ⊞Ｏυι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcexDsIgEIDhV7nxSI7h7ODg6OSgshMGxCZtgoUcnK@Prf/wJX9aoqQS8xhO1q3jNbaO91jRZW3ob1vV/tDPaxY0geD/aAyBk/LW1NFpW551ltiLoBKs5ugyhj8ReMu7E4HlMwFPzCEM@80/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｎ           Input a₀
   ⟦ ⟧          Wrap in a list
      Ａ         Input deltas as a list
  ⁺              Concatenate lists
 Ｅ              Map over elements
           ι    Current element
          υ     Predefined empty list variable
        ⊞Ｏ      Push and return updated list
       Π        Product
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print each value on its own line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 9 bytes

```
{(*\)x,y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pDK0azQqey9v9/AA)

Joins the first number to the second input as a list, and then returns successive results of multiplication

**Test Cases**

Enter your input after the function like below and then run, as I'm unsure how to use input properly for this language in TiO

```
{(*\)x,y}[1;1 5 3 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 13 bytes

```
p[*pz1<A]dsAx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBLCsMwDET3PYWhuzICS3bsLEoh5wghi@YAhW5KL5@O0ph@kH@x9TQTLdf1GEyDBW5hNJ2CXLgj23TwqxS6oIwj56jokGDvHIV/Km/id@rsufKfLAofHVfODzE7UklUB@SLqKhMdCByMSWiSb1@dU6teRY1UqIV/t78i2VINajxoCXmUrKL5g2dXdQPbtVcbDPI3252WaHP4KB@7CE5pr0jv7F3xvATrUMsiJ7ySIZCH9bDujKtt/F0e@p5mJb78FjXFw)

```
p[*pz1<A]dsAx
p               # Print the first element
  *p            # Multiply top elements on the stack
 [  z1<A]dsAx   # until only one element is left
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 3 bytes

```
\×⊂
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAgXMOX4oqCCgpmIDIgWzIxXQpmIDEgWzEgNSAzIDJdCmYgNyBbMSDCrzUgMyAyXQo=)